# MRP check product_qty on location_id OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I have a custom function on `mrp` module. I'm using OpenERP v7.

This function, should check if the product quantity on the `location_src_id` is sufficient to make a production order, but so far I have some errors on it, can't make it work, this is the function code:

```
    def _product_cantidad(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if order.product_qty > product_qty.location_src_id:

            return False
    return True
    _constraints = [
       (_product_cantidad, 'La cantidad especificada no puede ser producida debido a que no hay Stock suficiente', ['product_qty']),
]
```

This is my traceback:

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/mrp/mrp.py", line 518, in _product_cantidad
if order.product_qty > product_qty.location_src_id:
NameError: global name 'product_qty' is not defined
```

If product_qty specified on production order, is more than product_qty on source location, then popup a warning.

But I just can't make it work, `product_qty` is defined on the same class where I'm creating this function `mrp.production`, so I can't figure it out...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please give more code,, please specify what type of fields is product_qty ??

Comment: you can use this code to get product quantity of any location by its id:                                           context1.update({'states': ['done'], 'what': ('in', 'out'), 'location': 18})
            result = prod_obj_pool.get_product_available(cr, uid, [obj.product_id.id], context=context1)

Comment: Hey, thank you, going to try it :)

Comment: kk,, ur wlcme,, if it work notify me,, as i can make it an answer.. thank you.

Comment: please specify about product_qty field too..??

Comment: Hi Baiju, I don't understand your question, it's a field which it's used on openerp, to specify the quantity of whatever product, in production order, sale order, warehouse, etc...

Comment: Later, I'll edit my question to clarify you the situation

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code to get product quantity of any location by its id:

context1.update({'states': ['done'], 'what': ('in', 'out'), 'location': 18})

result = prod_obj_pool.get_product_available(cr, uid, [obj.product_id.id], context=context1)

Give **location id** and **product id**.

Comment: Hi, Baiju, I'm sorry, but could you clarify a bit more where i should use this code in my function?